# Docker: Push data container onto Docker Hub

Tags: docker, dockerhub, data-containers

I am really new at this Docker stuff, and even newer at Docker Hub, so please bear with me …

I have created a data container to use with my docker image (specifically, a data container to store data for a running `mssql-server-lnux` image). I know where it is on my local system.

I have a newly created account on Docker Hub and I *think* I want to push the data container on the hub. I say I *think* because I’m not sure that it’s the right way to go about it: I want to be able to use the data container from different machines.

If what I have said so far is in the right direction, then how do I push the docker image to the Hub, and how do I then access it later?

Answer (score 2):

You can't push containers, only images, the distinction is important.

Image is akin to a *class* of your container, and container is essentially an *instance* of your image.

So if you want to push to share your database then it's not a good idea - you would have to `docker commit` first and this would get ugly really fast.

But if you just want to start new instances of your mysql on different machines with fresh data containers (there will be no data initially) then go ahead and push the data container image.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think it does help, but could you clarify one more point. If the physical location of the container, current `/var/lib/docker/volumes/…/_data` on my Mac, were relocated to a cloud volume, I could create a new container on my other machines with the same Source? I wouldn’t involve Docker Hub at all?

Comment: hmm, don't think you can share the data under /var/lib/docker/... between more than one docker daemon, the only way to share the actual data from data container is to mount it out to some cloud volume with -v

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here are few steps. Please check if this helps.

1. Tag your image first. Let's say your image name is 'myapplication' and your docker hub user name is 'dockerhubusername'.

   `$ docker tag myapplication dockerhubusername/myapplication`
2. Login to docker hub using. Enter user name like 'dockerhubusername' and then password of docker hub account.

   `$ docker login`
3. Now push command.

   `$ docker push dockerhubusername/myapplication`

Now, login to your docker hub and check if you have image there. Remember, images are pushed to registry/repository like dockerhub not containers.

Comment: This push the application image, but what happens with the data volume?

Comment: data volume is always on the host machine. You can take backup of files if you want.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have tagged your image,

Use docker login to configure your docker hub credentials and use docker push to push your image to dockerhub.

> $ docker login
>
> $ docker push dockerhub_username/mssql-server-lnux

If you have not yet tagged the image,

> $ docker tag mssql-server-lnux dockerhub_username/mssql-server-lnux

To access your image later,

> $ docker pull dockerhub_username/mssql-server-lnux

References

1. [Docker Pull](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/)
2. [Docker Login](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/)